# Python Win32com Want to copy specific line from body part to excel

Tags: python, regex, outlook, win32com, office-automation

```
  I'm trying to copy a specific line from the mail body but I don't know how to do that. 
    I thought regex could solve my problem but didn't know how to implement it again.
    
    mail body:
    
    Line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
    line5
    line6 -  File Name
    line7 - count
    
        I want only want to copy the File Name & paste it into an excel file.
```

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as client

outlook = cliet.Dispaatch("Outlook.Application"),GetNameSpace("MAPI")

prod_path = outlook.Folders("emailId").Folders[1].Items

#print(prod_path.FolderPath)

mailbox = mailbox.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httmail:subject like 'subject')")

listofmails = []

for mail in mailbox:
     listofmails.append(mail.body)
     #print(mail.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of dealing with the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

   ```
    Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
      'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
      Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
      'Create e-mail item 
      Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
      With objMail 
       'Set body format to HTML 
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
       .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
       .Display 
      End With 
     End Sub
   ```
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

So, you can use the Word object model to find out the line of text required for you.